# ASP.NET multiple Client Callbacks

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, callback

I am currently working on changing all my DevExpress Callbacks into ASP Client callbacks.

The problem I am having is that there is one server function that all calls go to and one javascript function that receives the client callback.

If I would like to call the callback twice at the same time it gets mixed up and only does one or half of both.

For example, I have a button on my page that calls the callback. I also have a refresh every 10 seconds that goes back to the server to get updated data. If it's in middle of refreshing and I click a button, I have a problem.

How can I call multiple callbacks at one time?